# Radio buttons doing weird things with values

Tags: html, radio-button

I have some php generated yes/no radio buttons. When the buttons are given to the browser (tested in Chrome and Firefox) the yes button value is being turned to blank/null. I have verified that the html being passed is correct. I am now stumped.

An example of the code sent to the browser (this is the value sent from php script):

```
<label for="viol_comveh_yes">YES</label><input type="radio" name="YN_COMVEH_VIOL" value="yes" id="viol_comveh_yes" data-save="true"/>
```

On every one of these buttons the value is being turned to null.

Comment: do you have code? can you post it here?

Answer (score 0):

PHP sends only a value when the checkbox/radio button is selected.

That means that the name from the checkbox/radio contains the value. An example:

```
<input type="radio" name="Foo" value="bar" />
```

When it is post you have:

```
echo $_POST['Foo']; // bar
```

I hope this is what you are looking for!